# Pyhthon: pd.DateOffset causes duplicate index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to change the timestamp of my time series `dataframe`. The existing date-time of the first row is `01/01/2001  04:30:00`. I want to change it to `05/12/2011  19:30:00`, and the rest (up to five years of 5 minute record) should follow.

I used the following:
`df['DateTime'] = df['DateTime'] - pd.DateOffset(years=-10, months=-11, days=0, hours=9, minutes=0)`

It works, but it also introduces thousands of duplicates date-time.
I don't know yet what was the cause.

Curious how is the correct way to change the date-time as I wanted above?

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15KsKaoO6IroDlLC_HMj6iK2MeM5yPYcv/view?usp=sharing) is the data.

**Add 1:**
I cheked the original file for duplicate in DateTime column:

```
duplicaterows = df[df.duplicated(['DateTime'])]
print("Duplicate Rows:\n", duplicaterows)

# Result:    

Duplicate Rows:
                   DateTime   data
176252 2002-09-08 10:45:00  22.23
393863 2004-10-28 05:55:00  26.21
```

Two rows are shown, but I don't find them as duplicate. Don't know why?

**Add 2:**
For you who is still interested in this issue. Mistakes in conversion occur quite regularly. Namely, changes in the delta month occur every time the original timestamp transitioning from 28 February 23:55:00 to the next day which lasting for one month. Changes in the delta days and hours happened more frequently. No changes in the delta years observed.

```
original               new
28/02/2001 23:55:00    28/01/2012 14:55:00
01/03/2001 00:00:00    31/01/2012 15:00:00
```

The correct new timestamp in the second row should be `28/01/2012 15:00:00` instead of `31/01/2012 15:00:00`

Comment: Have you try to look at rows with duplicates after conversion, do they have duplicates in the original dataset? Can  you try posting them here?

Comment: @Quang Hoang, no, the original dataset does not contain any duplicate datetime.

Comment: Try this: `df[df.DateTime.duplicated(keep=False)]`. By default, `duplicated` only marks the 2nd occurrence onward (`keep='fisrt'`).

Comment: @Quang Hoang. ```keep=False``` or ```keep='first'```

Comment: `keep=False` gives you all duplicated.

Comment: Interesting problem. First glance at the output suggest that `2001-03-29` and `2001-03-30` gives the same output as `2012-03-04 15:00:00`. Maybe a bug in `DateOffset`?

Comment: @Quang Hoang. Using ```keep=False``` and ```keep='first'``` significantly reduce the record and duplicates are still many.

Comment: It is a difficult issue for me to solve