# Python: adding days to time epoch

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a dataframe time series with a DateTime column. The DateTime was converted to epoch timestamp using:

```
df['Epoch'] = df['DateTime'].astype('int64')//1e9
```

Now, I want to add to each row of Epoch:

```
year = 10  
month 10  
day = 29  
hour = 15  
minute = 0  
second = 0
```

Tried searching no result yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try add the offset before convert:

```
offset = pd.DateOffset(years=10, months=10, days=29, hours=15)
df['Epoch'] = (df['DateTime'] + offset).astype('int64')//1e9
```

Comment: I want to do it with epoch, because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56329470/pyhthon-pd-dateoffset-causes-duplicate-index that we discussed before